# PluggableAuth extension how to receive $_POST hidden data without show form to user?

Tags: mediawiki

I created a simple authentication extension that works in conjunction with PluggableAuth for the user to login automatically. Currently, I need two parameters: a username and a token. These parameters are generated by an external system that sends the data by hidden input. I can get the url data and authenticate correctly. But for security reasons I want to pass this data via $_POST and not via $_GET. But I cannot receive this data and store it in the session so that I can retrieve it in my authentication class. Basically, the user receives a link from a wiki page and Pluggableauth does the checks. But I can't find what code I can use to save the post in the session and retrieve it later. Does anyone have any examples of how to do this? Thanks!

Edit: For example, the user needs to go to [www.minhawiki.com/something](http://www.minhawiki.com/something), the external system sends the post data with username and password to this example page, but because of pluggableauth it redirects to Special:UserLogin, then to PluggableAuthLogin and then to my authentication extension. I've tried to get the data on all these redirects but none of them work. The only way that worked to get the data was to direct the post directly to Special:UserLogin but that way I can't redirect to the login page.

Comment: Is https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classMediaWiki_1_1Session_1_1Session.html#a8ebc6d6d6dfe5faede52ae62e9608763 what you are looking for?

Comment: I've tried it that way but the data isn't passed.

Comment: Did you call https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classMediaWiki_1_1Session_1_1Session.html#a7a2cdd64c8ce69abf5b38abf5a937ef7 afterwards?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I can't get the data because PluggableAuth automatically redirects the page and I can't get the $_POST data, it always returns null.